# How to detect airplane mode on whole application in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, airplane-mode

I am working on developing an Android app that will detect airplane mode throughout whole application. where to i add this code?

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {        
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;          
    } else {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Add this method into your Java class :). What is your question?

Comment: It depends on when do want to detect.. On start of your app ?

Comment: You can create your own custom activity and put this code there and extends your custom activity

Comment: `boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;`. and for JB use  Settings.Global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code where you want to detect whether connection is available.

for example:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
boolean isonair = myApp.isAirplaneModeOn(this);
Toast.makeText(this, "IS on AIR? " + isonair, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

If you want to have an access for static function use them in Application class:

```
public class myApp extends Application {
public static function isAirplaneModeOn() {
...
}
}
```

in any activity use this access: `myApp.isAirplaneModeOn()`

do not forget update your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:name=".myApp" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this is your class name
        android:icon="@drawable/somedrawable"
        android:label="@string/app_alias"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: I want to detect in whole application in all place..

Comment: Really!! we need to add static method into Application class?

Comment: @PankajKumar , he wanted this solution

Answer (score 0):

Create a Interface like **AirplaneModeManager** whose Implementation extending **broadcast receiver** to get notified in the scenario when airplane mode is activated

you can use this code in Implementation to keep a track and use its methods in whole application to get the status !!